# New Windows on Foxit reader on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: pdf

How can I open A PDF file in a new window in Foxit reader on UBuntu 18.04? On windows, if you check the 'allow multiple instances' box in preferences, you can just drug and make the tab a new window. In Ubuntu, I couldn't do that and even find the same option in the preference.

Thanks!